# How to program a UITableViewCell to briefly blink?

Tags: uitableview

I have a UITableView into which I've just inserted a new row, retrieved the NSIndexPath of this row, and scrolled to it.  How can I cause the cell at this row to briefly blink?

```
int indexOfRow = //retrieve row index
NSIndexPath *indexPath =  [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexOfRow inSection:0];
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
//cause cell to blink
```

What follows?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
UITableViewCell *tableCell = [[self tableView] cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[tableCell setHighlighted:YES animated:NO];
[tableCell setHighlighted:NO animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void) someMethod {
    //your other code
    //...

    UITableViewCell *tableCell = [[self tableView] cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [tableCell setHighlighted:YES animated:NO];
    [self performSelector:@selector(completeCellBlink:) withObject:tableCell afterDelay:0.2];

}

- (void) completeCellBlink: (UITableViewCell*) cell {
    [tableCell setHighlighted:NO animated:YES];
}
```

The delay is in seconds, and you can of course change that value to adjust the visual impression.